# I can't install npm install --save react-tilt

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-install

```
C:\Users\JohnSam\Desktop\React\smartapp>npm install --save react-tilt
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: smartbrain2@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^17.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0-beta || ^16.0.0" from react-tilt@0.1.4
npm ERR! node_modules/react-tilt
npm ERR!   react-tilt@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps       
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\Sengk\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Sengk\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-11-30T08_35_11_646Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Looks like react-tilt isn't using React 17 yet. You can try downgrading your react dependency, or raise an issue at react-tilt and wait for an update

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error says that the version of React you are using (17.0.2) is not compatible with `react-tilt`.

When looking at the [package.json](https://github.com/jonathandion/react-tilt/blob/master/package.json) file of `react-tilt`, you'll see it requires a peerdependency of `react@^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0-beta || ^16.0.0`.

NPM enforces correct peerdependencies by default since npm v7. If you realy want to, you can ignore this check and run `npm install --save --legacy-peer-deps  react-tilt`.

Note that this means there is no guarantee this package will completely work with React 17.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using React 18.2.0 and had the same issue with react-tilt and also some other packages that were using React 18.0.0 or 17.0.0. I ran the following command to fix the issue

`npm install --legacy-peer-deps  react-tilt` or

`npm install --save --legacy-peer-deps  package-name`

Comment: Please don't post duplicate answers. If something worked for you, upvote it. If it worked for another version or platform, _maybe_ add a comment to the answer which solved it for you. (You need 30 rep to submit comments, though.)

Comment: Thanks, I will keep that in mind, from next time onwards :)